# Retrieve a portion of data from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in a column in my database, and I have literally no idea what to do to retrieve a piece of the data that I want:

```
a:2:{i:1;a:3:{s:8:"property";s:10:"Promo code";s:5:"logic";s:11:"Is equal to";s:5:"value";s:12:"DISCOUNTTIME";}i:2;a:3:{s:8:"property";s:15:"Promo use count";s:5:"logic";s:11:"Is equal to";s:5:"value";s:1:"0";}}
```

I'm trying to retrieve only DISCOUNTTIME.  I can handle the basics like

```
"SELECT x FROM y WHERE id = z"
```

but just have no idea how to deal with the way this data is formatted.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at php [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) - it looks like your string is in that format

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  I'll try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Once you try it and see that it is a serialized PHP multidimensional array, question why you're storing multiple values in a single column. It's bad DB design, so if you have the option, don't do it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm pulling this data from a WordPress plugin.  Not my design :(

As an aside, unserialize() does work.  I'm pulling what I need now from the array.  Thanks Tudor.  I'll mark as answered :)

Comment: I TOTALLY subscribe to Dan's comment - even though I saw such ways of storing data in very known applications like Wordpress, I totally recommend avoiding it. Right now, I am worknig on a project where the id's of childs from a 1..n relationship is held like that - it's performance hell

Comment: yeah, it's the Shopp plugin for WordPress.  I don't dabble in databases a lot (except for basic queries) and have rarely seen data stored like this.

Answer (score 0):

Which part of the expression are you trying to retrieve?  Perhaps the "s:12" part before DISCOUNTTIME?  If you're just trying to find the rows which contain DISCOUNTTIME then you can use the MySQL INSTR operator: SELECT * FROM y WHERE INSTR(columnname, 'DISCOUNTTIME')>0

If you're trying to find some piece of text related to DISCOUNTTIME, e.g. "s:12:" then you can do it by combining INSTR with other expressions.  If you know the preceding text will always have five characters like "s:12:" then you can SELECT SUBSTR(columnname, INSTR-5, 5)

If the string structure is very complex you might be better off writing a program to query the database and then use regexp or other techniques to extract the string.

See MySQL String Functions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Comment: I think this would have worked too, because the data i need is always prefixed with s:12. Either way I started using unserialize(), so I'm going to stick with it. Thanks anyways!